# <bits/stdc++.h>

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Хочу узнать про библиотеку . Буду благодарен, если объясните простыми словами.

Answer (score 1):

Нужно просто найти этот файл и открыть его, как сразу все станет понятным. У меня этот файл находится по такому пути "/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/6.4.0/include/g++-v6/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bits/stdc++.h". А внутри всевозможные "include" - начиная от банальных vector и map, и закачивая complex, future, ratio и другими.

Обычно этот файл добавляют, когда делают тестовый пример на с++ и не хотят вручную добавлять кучу разных инклудов (или просто захламлять пример). Для "продакшн кода" обычно такое включение считается не приемлемым.

Comment: *"считается не приемлемым"* Потому что компилируется дольше и работает не на всех компиляторах.

Comment: это как бы логично.

Comment: спасибо большое. я новичек и не знал как вставлять инглиш текст